# Is it dangerous to use wooden cutlery and cutting boards with raw meat?

Tags: hygiene, cooking, disease

I have heard multiple times that "one should never cut raw meat on a wooden cutting board nor mix it using a wooden spoon."

The reason most often cited is that apparently bacteria can survive in the wood's pores.

I also found [this PDF](http://www.foodsafety.wisc.edu/assets/pdf_Files/Care%20and%20Cleaning%20of%20Butcher%20Blocks%20and%20Wooden%20Cutting%20Boards.pdf) from the University of Wisconsin–Madison where it is written:

> **Using.** Avoid cutting raw meat or poultry directly on a butcher block or
>   wooden cutting board. Instead, place a plastic cutting board on the
>   wooden surface and use the plastic board as the cutting surface. This
>   will protect the wood and prevent it from becoming contaminated.

Is there any truth in this claim?

Comment: This question might find even better answers on https://cooking.stackexchange.com

Comment: Wood is quite possibly the [safer choice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/621).

Answer (score 32):

According to [research at UC-Davis](http://faculty.vetmed.ucdavis.edu/faculty/docliver/Research/cuttingboard.htm), quite the opposite is true.  The key finding:

> Our safety concern was that bacteria such as Escherichia coli O157:H7
>   and Salmonella, which might contaminate a work surface when raw meat
>   was being prepared, ought not remain on the surface to contaminate
>   other foods that might be eaten without further cooking. We soon found
>   that disease bacteria such as these were not recoverable from wooden
>   surfaces in a short time after they were applied, unless very large
>   numbers were used. New plastic surfaces allowed the bacteria to
>   persist, but were easily cleaned and disinfected. However, wooden
>   boards that had been used and had many knife cuts acted almost the
>   same as new wood, whereas plastic surfaces that were knife-scarred
>   were impossible to clean and disinfect manually, especially when food
>   residues such as chicken fat were present.

All species of hardwood tested were found to have [bacteriostatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacteriostatic_agent) or antibacterial properties that plastic lacks, which compensated for the inability to easily clean the wood's pores.

Comment: Wow, an unexpected answer. I would have accepted the conventional wisdom. Shows you learn something new every day.